# Apache Directory Authentication Failed?

Tags: windows, openldap, apache-directory

I am trying to connect the OpenLdap through Apache Directory Studio and its working upto Network Parameter and check Network Parameter working fine.

But Next step i am trying to Authentication and its failed with below message.

> The authentication failed
>    - The response queue has been emptied, no response was found.   org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapException: The
>   response queue has been emptied, no response was found.   at
>   org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.bind(LdapNetworkConnection.java:1327)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper$2.run(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:368)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.runAndMonitor(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1269)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.doBind(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:460)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.bind(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:306)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.jobs.CheckBindRunnable.run(CheckBindRunnable.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.ui.RunnableContextRunner$1.run(RunnableContextRunner.java:127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
>   Caused by:
>   org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapException: TimeOut
>   occurred  at
>   org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.bind(LdapNetworkConnection.java:1305)
>     ... 7 more
>
> The response queue has been emptied, no response was found.